# Is $f(2x) -3$ a fancy way of saying the function is compressed and translated?

Tags: functions

Say you have a function $f(x)$. Would writing $f(2x) - 3$ be the same as compressing $f(x)$ by a factor of $1/2$ and translating it down by three?

Comment: That's one possible interpretation, yes. Saying that it's a "fancy way" is very subjective. I for instance, rather than fancy, would say "compact" (in the non-mathematical sense of course) or "terse". Also, there are *many* other possible interpretations of $f(2x) - 3$, depending on what problem you apply it to.

Comment: Also, your function $f$ is defined on some domain. If $2x$ is outside this domain, then your composite function might not be defined there. Take for instance the real function  $f(x) = \sqrt{1-x}$, defined on $]-\infty, 1]$ : $f(2x)$ is not defined for $x=3/4$. So no, it's not exactly the same. It's a good interpretation nonetheless.

Comment: Compressing horizontally around $x=0$. More generally, $a_yf\left(\dfrac{x-b_x}{c_x}\right)+b_y$ scales/translates both abscissas and ordinates.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: not saying there is a problem, just pointing out that it's not quite the same. I think we are in agreement that "the new function is not the same", to quote your words,

Comment: @YvesDaoust: I meant it as a shortcut to avoid repeating the OP's question "would writing f(2x)−3 be the same as compressing f(x) by a factor of 1/2 and translating it down by three?" - no, it's not quite the same.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: I understand what you're saying, and I do agree. I believe you attach too much meaning to my comment, which was inspired by the notation $f(x)$ in the original question. I freely admit that I was nitpicking :-D, which is why I made a comment and not an answer ; in fact, I think  if the OP had written $f$ instead of $f(x)$ I would not have reacted. And maybe I shouldn't have anyway,

Comment: @lmsteffan: I am deleting my comments.

Answer (score 1):

Yes: suppose the pair of numbers $(\alpha,\beta)$ lies on the graph of $f$, so $f(\alpha)=\beta$. Let $g(x)=f(2x)-3$. Then, $g(\alpha/2)=\beta-3$, and so the pair of numbers $(\alpha/2,\beta-3)$ lies on the graph of $g$. Therefore, each point has been translated from $(\alpha,\beta)$ to $(\alpha/2,\beta-3)$, which is the same as halving all of the $x$-values (a vertical stretch of scale factor $1/2$), and subtracting $3$ from all of the $y$-values (a vertical translation of $3$ units downwards).